# An application to Economics. My original application

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

My Program gives me an error when I run it saying that I passed 3 arguments into top.geometry(x,y) when I only have passed two.

```
I've tried using "foo" and that made it worse. What I am trying to do is create a tkinter application that will calculate the amount of money adjusted for inflation at a future year.

    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    import math
    from math import *
    import matplotlib 
    from matplotlib import *
    from pylab import plot, show

    "set window geometry variables"
    (x,y) = (1650,1100)
    "Define Empty List"
    x_Data = []
    y_Data = []
    "Create Window and Define it's Size"
    top = tk.Tk()
    top.title("Inflation Adjusted Calculator")
    top.geometry(x,y)




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacob/Documents/Python Programs/Inflation_Calculator_Program.py", line 17, in <module>
    top.geometry(x,y)
TypeError: wm_geometry() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you are writing what appear to be comments in quotes?

Comment: `geometry` takes a `str`: `top.geometry(f'{x}x{y}')`, then you don't have to change the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `geometry` is the following

> Set geometry to NEWGEOMETRY of the form =widthxheight+x+y. Return
>           current value if None is given.

Hence to set the value of your window to be 1650x1100, you can simply pass it into the `geometry` method.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import math
from math import *
import matplotlib 
from matplotlib import *
from pylab import plot, show

# Define Empty List
x_Data = []
y_Data = []
# Create Window and Define it's Size
top = tk.Tk()
top.title("Inflation Adjusted Calculator")
top.geometry('1650x1100')
mainloop()
```